# Are private or password-protected apps acceptable in the Apple AppStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Simple question - can I put an app in Apple's AppStore which is only functional for those who have a username & password? This is for a client who wants to distribute their app only to a select number of people. The Enterprise license is not an option, and while ad-hoc distribution is, I'd prefer to go through the store.

As the material is semi-sensitive, I'd need to keep the description to a minimum (eg. this app is only for XYZ users, and requires a password), and screenshot to just a single screen of the login page.

Does anyone know of any apps in the store like this?

Comment: Hi, did you ever get a definitive answer? Do you know what the current rules are regarding this?

Comment: Sorry, no further info from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These apps are more readily rejected, but Apple doesn't explicitly disallow this. You will have to provide them a test login during the application approval process.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you say they're more readily rejected? Experience? Guess-work?

Comment: Experience and time on their official developer forums. Anything that skirts their other potential revenue (like from the Enterprise program, for example) or makes it easier for the developer to hide bad behavior is scrutinized more closely.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll leave this open for a while longer to see if anyone comes up with some concrete examples, and if not I'll accept your answer. Thanks.